# RavenDB.Client and NetCoreApp1.0 won't connect

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ravendb

I'm trying to use RavenDB in my aspnet5 application built on netcoreapp1.0
I'm running this code:

```
 IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore()
              {
                Url = "http://localhost:8080"
              }.Initialize();
string[] databaseNames = store.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin.GetDatabaseNames(1);
```

and my project.json look like:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen": "6.0.0-beta901",
    "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi": "6.0.0-beta901",
    "RavenDB.Client": "3.5.0-rc-35173"
},

"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "netstandard1.6",
        "portable-net452+win81"
      ]
    }
  }, ...
```

it fails with this exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll

Additional information: SafeHandle cannot be null.
```

This exact same code has been tested on .net 45 and worked. any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: your code looks fine, and it works here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by silencing the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". This is caused due to a bad exception handling in RavenDB. It looks like it works normal even if there's an inner CLR exception.